# Intercept service on cypress (header attribute is not set)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, playwright

I am trying to make a cypress which clicks on a submit button using intercept.

So my code is as below :

```js
cy.intercept("*/service/excel/*", {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: "Mock Submit Service",
    headers: {
            'Content-Disposition' : "attachment; filename=test_20231201-20231207.xlsm",
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
             },
   }).as("downloadRequest");

cy.get('#test-download').click();
```

But I am getting the following error on console log

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')
    at o.saveAsExcel (src_app_features_reporting_reporting_module_ts.b20aeb1a83e76759.js:1:165362)
    at Object.next (src_app_features_reporting_reporting_module_ts.b20aeb1a83e76759.js:1:164909)
    at b.next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2402501)
    at p._next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2402185)
    at p.next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2401880)
    at O._next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2402185)
    at O.next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2401880)
    at main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2414119
    at O._next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2412202)
    at O.next (main.a6852359003f059f.js:1:2401880)
```

Observing the network I don't see any content-disposition defined, content-type is defined as content-type: text/html and the loading bar is stuck.

The method saveAsExcel is a method on my component which is defined as follow :

```js
    saveAsExcel(res) {
        if (res.body !== null && res.body !== undefined) {
            let contentDisposition = res.headers.get('content-disposition');
            let fileName = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].trim();
            FileSaver.saveAs(res.body, fileName);
        } else {
            this.growlMessageService.growlMessage('search_results_none', 'INFO');
        }
    }
```

Could you help me please ?